# wxPython Syntax Highlight Widget

Tags: python, syntax, wxpython

Is there a widget similar to **TextCtr** in **wxPython** that would add syntax highlight to the text field. 
I went over documentation but couldn't really find anything.

If not, how can i create it myself. I need just simple HTML highlight. Thanks

Comment: [WxStyledTextCtrl](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxStyledTextCtrl)?

Comment: Thanks! I am getting an error though, AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'StyledTextCtrl'..do you have any ideas?

Comment: @pythonm i did but i still get an error http://pastebin.com/sSNwvQm4

Comment: @PedroRomano I am on Mac OSX Lion x64, i have installed python 2.7.3 x32 from python.org and wxpython ver. 2.9 carbon

Comment: I found the error, you have to do both import wx and import wx.stc..thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several places to look for examples of this sort. The StyledTextCtrl, PyShell / PyCrust and Editra. PyShell / PyCrust have a demo in the official wxPython demo that actually show syntax highlighting. Editra is distributed with wx 2.8 and 2.9, but I'm not sure if it's included in the bleeding edge Phoenix release. However, I think it does syntax highlighting for multiple languages. You can also download it here: http://editra.org/